# ES/Nest (C#) newbie : " 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value" error

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am a total newbie to ES/Nest & C# and really stuck on a problem. I have an ES index with a very simple document structure and trying to search on `context` field. and I get this error:

> Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: 'Unexpected
>   character encountered while parsing value: [. Path
>   'hits.hits[0]._source.context', line 1, position 452.'

I gather the error is because of null values in the context fields (when I comment out context from the class, it works fine). But I am not sure how to get it to ignore the null values or leave them out entirely.

```
       var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/mydata");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        string[] qq = { "beach","dog" };
        var tq = new TermsQuery
        {
            Name = "named_query",
            Terms = qq,
        };
        var request = new SearchRequest
        {
            From = 0,
            Size = 10,
            Query = tq
        };

        var response = client.Search<Doc>(request);
        foreach (Doc value in response.Hits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

and this is my mapping class definition:

```
 public  class Doc
    { 
        public  string _id { get; set; }
        public  DateTime created_at { get;set;}
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public string Context { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample response where you see this exception? You can capture it with something like Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did use fiddler to find the issue the field was a multivalued and I needed to modify the tag field to a list<type>. Thanks for your help. Perhaps you can post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the JSON is returning an array for the `Context` property, but the property itself is a `string`. We know it's an array because the exception message indicates a parsing error when encountering an opening square bracket

> 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [

This is easily solved by making `Context` a string collection e.g. `string[]`, `IEnumerable<string>`, or whatever collection type makes the most sense for your model.

[Any field can have 0, 1 or more values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_multivalue_fields); you do not need create specific datatype collection to index multiple values for a field. The only caveat is that they all have to be the same datatype.